# Hyperbolic equations with three terms

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, 3d

The equation of a hyperbola is

$ x^2 - y^2 = r $

Assuming $ a = b = 0 $

Suppose now the equation

$ x^2 - y^2 + z^2 = r $

What kind of curve would this equation parametrize ? What is its geometry?

Since $ x^2 + y^2 = r $ is the equation of a circle would this be like a mix between a hyperbola (in the xy plane) and a circle (in the yz plane) ?

How does a variation in r change the shape of this curve?

Suppose we scale the variables by some factors

$ x^2 - ky^2 + mz^2 = r $

How would this factors affect the shape?

Comment: [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/3d/23e8c060cb).

Comment: It is not a curve but a surface since the one equation provides one constraint in 3D space of $(x,y,z)$.

Comment: Your idea to look at the traces of this surface in planes perpendicular to the $y$-axis, and in planes containing the $y$-axis (for example, the $xy$-plane or the $yz$-plane) is a good one.

Answer (score 1):

Take the surface $$x^2-y^2+z^2=r,$$ for some $r>0$.

If we project onto a plane $x=c$, we get $$-y^2+z^2=r-c^2,$$ a hyperbola (depending on the sign of $r-c^2$ we may get a rotated hyperbola).

Doing the same with $y=c$, we get $$x^2+z^2=r+c^2,$$ which is always a circumference.

If we project onto a plane $z=c$, we get $$x^2-y^2=r-c^2,$$ that is, a hyperbola again.

The result is a **one-sheet hyperboloid** (I suggest you use software to graph the surface and all the previous projections)

In case $r$ was $0$ we would get a cone and if $r<0$ we would get a two-sheet hyperboloid (for some $c$ we wouldn't get circumferences in the second projection).

For your last enquiry, I will asume $k,m>0$ and will leave other cases for you as an exercise. You just need to notice that the change of variables $$x'=x, y'=\sqrt{k}y, z'=\sqrt{m}z$$ reduces the equation to the previously studied case (if you went the 'projections route' the only difference would be that you would get ellipses instead of circumferences).

Comment: Thank you, do you know about some good 3d plotting software i could use to visualize this?

Comment: Desmos, wolfram alpha...